How do sitting politicians do their job and also campaign?
I am a technology professional who has held several jobs over my career. When transitioning jobs, I can find it difficult to manage fulfilling the responsibilities of my current job while actively hunting for a new position. However, for me this process is mostly talking with recruiters on the phone or browsing job sites.
How do sitting politicians who are also campaigning manage to fulfil their current job duties while extensively touring and making public appearances? This seems the most difficult for presidential candidates who tour the widest area.
Is there any possible recourse against an elected official who is neglecting their duties to campaign?

In what sense it is not the job of the politician to communicate with their electorate and maintain the relationship through political campaigning?
The question you're posing is akin to asking how a salesman is able to do his job whilst touring customer premises and talking to customers. Or how a company chairman finds time to do his job between meetings.
Even though I recognise it's not conventionally considered part of the job of an employed professional to seek new and better employment, the expectation of state lawmakers who oversee a functioning jobs market is that some time is occasionally allocated to this activity and that workers sense and respond to market signals.
So it's a misconceived question in its entirety. You can argue about whether a politician is doing their job well, and the ultimate recourse to a politician doing their job badly is supposed to be ejection from office, but it is certainly part of their duties to seek and maintain election to an office.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
